# How to use ggplot2 legend to denote different geoms

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to plot points from a .csv file that is just a column used a x values and a column used a y values. I am a little confused as to how ggplot decides what to make a legend for and haven't found any good examples online.

**I would like the legend to show that `geom_point` is stress vs strain, and my `geom_smooth` is the best fit line.**

Here is my code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
imported = read.csv("data.csv")

Strain = imported$Strain
Stress = imported$Stress..N.m.2.
err = .0005

gg <-
  ggplot(imported, aes(x=Strain, y=Stress)) + 
  geom_point(aes(group = "Points"), shape = 79, colour = "black", size = 2, stroke = 4) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "orange") + 
  geom_errorbarh(xmin = Strain - err, xmax = Strain + err, show.legend = TRUE) + 
  theme_gray() + ggtitle("Stress vs Strain") + 
  theme(legend.position = "top")

gg
```

And it is producing the following plot:
[my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0q4Z.png)

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve. In `ggplot` legends are automatically added for specific aesthetics (like `colour`, `fill`, `linetype` etc.).The `group` aesthetic  doesn't seem to serve any purpose in your code. Can you clarify on what you're trying to do? What would you like to include in the legend? Lastly: Please make your example reproducible by including sample data. Nobody but you has access to `imported`.

Comment: The `show.legend` option in `geom_errorbarh` determines whether the error bar layer should be included around any related geoms in a legend. For instance, if you took away `colour = "black"` from the `geom_point` code, and added `aes(color = Strain > 1)`, I expect you'd get a legend for the point color, and those might include error bars in the legend. Hard to confirm since you don't include sample data.

Comment: PS BTW. What you're doing can be very dangerous: You're using `data = imported` but then refer to `Strain` and `Stress` which are global variables. That's not the `ggplot` way. The whole point of the `data` function argument is to specify the `data.frame` where `ggplot` should look for columns containing your data that you'd like to plot.

Comment: What I am trying to do is take my data that is just x and y coordinates and get a legend that basically just says that my geom_point is stress vs strain, and my geom_smooth is the best fit line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: added approach at top to create legend for each geom, by creating dummy mapping to separate aesthetics.**

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = "point")) +   # dummy mapping to color
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "orange",
               aes(linetype = "best fit")) +  # dummy mapping to linetype
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = mpg - 2, xmax = mpg + 1)) +

  scale_color_manual(name = "Stress vs. Strain", values = "black") +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Best fit line", values = "solid")
```

[image]

---

**original answer**:

Note the difference in legend here:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, color = as.character(cyl))) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = mpg - 2, xmax = mpg + 1), 
      show.legend = TRUE)  # error bars reflected in legend
```

[image: with error bar in legend]

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, color = as.character(cyl))) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = mpg - 2, xmax = mpg + 1), 
      show.legend = FALSE)   # error bars not shown in legend
```

[image: without error bar in legend]

Comment: I think you might have uploaded the same plot for both code snippets by accident, so I re-generated the output from your first snippet & uploaded that.

Comment: Okay this helped a bit but I'm still confused as to how I would get a legend if I only have x and y coordinates that basically just says that my geom_point is stress vs strain, and my geom_smooth is the best fit line.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a straightforward way to do this. Legends in ggplot are used to show how an aesthetic (like color, size, shape, etc.) is mapped to a variable. They are not typically used to label separate geoms. That said, there is probably a hacky way to do this.  (BTW, I have edited your question since this goal was not explicit in the original.)